# How to escape quotes in the bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, escape-characters

I'm having trouble with escaping characters in bash. I'd like to escape single and double quotes while running a command under a different user. For the purposes of this question let's say I want to echo the following on the screen:

```
'single quote phrase' "double quote phrase"
```

How can I escape all the special chars, if I also need to switch to a different user:

```
sudo su USER -c "echo \"'single quote phrase' \"double quote phrase\"\""
```

Of course, this doesn't produce the right result.

Comment: ... except it DOES work as expected, you have to escape quotes 2 times since your string is nested within other string. It would work the same in any other programming language: `bash -c "echo \"'single quote phrase' \\\"double quote phrase\\\"\""`

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You can use the following string literal syntax:

```
> echo $'\'single quote phrase\' "double quote phrase"'
'single quote phrase' "double quote phrase"
```

#### From `man bash`

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands
>   to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified  by
>   the
>          ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:
>
> ```
>           \a     alert (bell)
>           \b     backspace
>           \e
>           \E     an escape character
>           \f     form feed
>           \n     new line
>           \r     carriage return
>           \t     horizontal tab
>           \v     vertical tab
>           \\     backslash
>           \'     single quote
>           \"     double quote
>           \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (one to three digits)
>           \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two hex digits)
>           \cx    a control-x character
> ```

Comment: More details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16605140/149221

Comment: Just a note to others if the "From man bash" doesn't clue you in, this *will not work on `sh`* even though that's how the *question* was [mis?]tagged.

Comment: @Hashbrown good catch, fixed.

Answer (score 47):

Simple example of escaping quotes in shell:

```
$ echo 'abc'\''abc'
abc'abc
$ echo "abc"\""abc"
abc"abc
```

It's done by finishing already opened one (`'`), placing escaped one (`\'`), then opening another one (`'`).

Alternatively:

```
$ echo 'abc'"'"'abc'
abc'abc
$ echo "abc"'"'"abc"
abc"abc
```

It's done by finishing already opened one (`'`), placing quote in another quote (`"'"`), then opening another one (`'`).

Related: [How to escape single-quotes within single-quoted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/55075) at stackoverflow SE

Answer (score 18):

In a POSIX shell, assuming in your string there is no variable, command or history expansion, and there is no newline, follow these basic prescriptions:

1. To quote a generic string with single quotes, perform the following actions:

   1. Substitute any sequence of non-single-quote characters with the same sequence with added leading and trailing single quotes: `'aaa'  ==>  ''aaa''`
   2. Escape with a backslash every *preexisting* single quote character: `'  ==>  \'`
      In particular, `''aaa'' ==> \''aaa'\'`
2. To quote a generic string with double quotes, perform the following actions:

   1. Add leading and trailing double quotes: `aaa  ==>  "aaa"`
   2. Escape with a backslash every double quote character and every backslash character: `"  ==>  \", \  ==>  \\`

A couple of examples:

```
''aaa""bbb''ccc\\ddd''  ==>  \'\''aaa""bbb'\'\''ccc\\ddd'\'\'
                        ==>  "''aaa\"\"bbb''ccc\\\\ddd''"
```

so that you example could be expanded with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo \''aaa'\'' "bbb"'
echo "'aaa' \"bbb\""

sudo su enzotib -c 'echo \'\'\''aaa'\''\'\'\'' "bbb"'\'
sudo su enzotib -c 'echo "'\''aaa'\'' \"bbb\""'

sudo su enzotib -c "echo \\''aaa'\\'' \"bbb\"'"
sudo su enzotib -c "echo \"'aaa' \\\"bbb\\\"\""
```

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer works for simple (one level) quoting:

```
$ echo $'\'single quote phrase\' "double quote phrase"'
'single quote phrase' "double quote phrase"
```

To get the command presented to work, you need to quote twice.
This script could do all the work:

```
#!/bin/bash

quote () { 
    local quoted=${1//\'/\'\\\'\'};
    printf "'%s'" "$quoted"
}

read -r line <<-\_line_to_quote_
'single quote phrase' "double quote phrase"
_line_to_quote_

quote "$line"; echo
quote "echo $(quote "$line")"; echo
```

Execute the script to get:

```
$ script
''\''single quote phrase'\'' "double quote phrase"'
'echo '\'''\''\'\'''\''single quote phrase'\''\'\'''\'' "double quote phrase"'\'''
```

The first line works for simple echo:

```
$ echo ''\''single quote phrase'\'' "double quote phrase"'
'single quote phrase' "double quote phrase"
```

The second line will work for the double quoted command:

```
sudo su USER -c 'echo '\'''\''\'\'''\''single quote phrase'\''\'\'''\'' "double quote phrase"'\'''
```

Comment: This quote function is amazing! It can be used in scripts to do arbitrarily deep quoting without being exponentially uglier. e.g. `eval "eval $(quote "eval $(quote "eval $(quote "echo test")")")"`

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple

Remove double quotes by piping your output to `sed`

```
sed 's/"//g'
```

#### Example

```
somethingThatProducesDoubleQuotesHere | removeDoubleQuotes
```

Or you could use a method to make life easier in the future

```
removeDoubleQuotes() {
  sed 's/"//g'
  # EXAMPLES:
  # somethingThatProducesDoubleQuotesHere | removeDoubleQuotes
}
```