# Retry commands on failure until success but with different flags

Tags: bash, command

So, I'm trying to retry failing or command-line with errors, *BUT* with different flags each time it retry...

I already know how to retry command on failure:

```bsh
while ! "$@"
do
  :
  sleep 1
done
```

As an example, I'll use the function above on a failing command on purpose to illustrate:

```bsh
retry ls test # here this will usually fail and thus retry infinitely
```

I'm aware this:

- Retry infinitely (until the retried command succeed or return an exit code that is interpreted by the shell as successful)
- Doesn't take into consideration any kind of errors/exit code other than failure whatsover

And all of the above is the wanted/expected effect.

Only thing I'm trying to add to that is support for additional flag when "retrying" N command (which I'll need to either supply as argument to the function or hardcode in the function depending on cases...)

Here what I tried:

```
bash
while ! "$(echo "$@" | sed "s/^pattern/pattern --otherflag/g")"
do
  :
  sleep 1
done
```

Usage:

```bsh
retry ls pattern
```

Where the new command will become `ls pattern --otherflag` (which will obviously fail, but this is beside the point)

2nd Method:

```bsh
while ! "${@/pattern/pattern --otherflag}"
do
  :
  sleep 1
done
```

Same usage as above...

Here it will give the same result as above.

Now this seems to work on first glance, but if the supplied/failing command contain any kind of quotes, which usually come unquoted, the output/retried command will then have the quotes removed/ignored...

So following above two method/example, a command such as `ls pattern "file"` will become `ls pattern --otherflag file` where `file` doesn't have any quotes (same happen with single quotes).

To fix this I tried this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244556/409852)'s `quote` function but didn't manage to get satisfying result.
Furthermore, it also seems like it doesn't wait/use the added flag only on failure (eg: when the retry function kicks in) but instead run it before it even fail, with the additional flags.

I don't want to have to use a `if` block/condition if possible and prefer to stay as close as possible to the above snippet. Prefer `bash` or/and `sh` alternative. Any feedback/answer is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your script is called `retry.sh`, and its called from the shell with the command line `retry.sh ls "foo bar"`, the positional parameters (arguments, i.e. `$1`, `$2`...) within the script will be `ls` and `foo bar`. Note that while quotes are a way to protect white space and other special characters on the shell command line, the quotes don't exist any more within the launched script. Instead, what you have is basically an array of strings.

Now, `"$@"` treats the distinct parameters properly: it expands each to a distinct word. But if you do `"$(echo "$@" | sed "s/^pattern/pattern --otherflag/g")"`, the `echo` concatenates its arguments to one string, and the quotes around the whole command substitution keep it as one string, instead of having word splitting split it on white space. Not that splitting would help, since at this point the separation between the original arguments is lost, and the one argument `foo bar` would be the same as the two arguments `foo` and `bar`.

Also, `"${@/pattern/pattern --otherflag}"` will do the replacement within each positional parameter individually, so with the parameters `ls` and `foo bar`, `"${@/ls/ls --otherflag}"` would result in the two words `ls --otherflag`. This would look for a command literally called `ls --otherflag`, the same as if you were to run `"ls --otherflag"` on the shell command line.

---

What you want is `ls`, `--otherflag`, `foo bar`, i.e. to add the flag as an additional argument.

While you *could* take all the arguments from `$@`, escape them for shell processing and join them together to make a valid command line, then edit that command line, and feed it back to the shell with `eval`, it's safer to just deal with the list as a list.

Adding an argument to the end would be relatively easy:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! "$@"; then
    echo "failed, retrying..."
    if ! "$@" --otherflag; then
        echo "nope, still failed"
    fi
fi
```

Adding one to the middle requires arrays or slicing `$@`. E.g. to add the flag to the second position:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! "$@"; then
    echo "failed, retrying..."
    if ! "$1" --otherflag "${@:2}"; then
        echo "nope, still failed"
    fi
fi
```

`"${@:n:m}"` expands to the first *m* positional parameters starting at index *n*,
or until the end of the list *m* is not given. So `"$1"` is the first argument (same as `"${@:1:1}"`), and `"${@:2}"` the rest.

Somewhat related: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)

Comment: It's a great answer, (and I appreciate the detailed info too) but it seems it didn't kept the "retry infinitely" part of the original snippet? I know i could use a `while True` but preferred to "retry infinitely until success" like the original snippet did if possible :) (eg: using the `while !` method)

Comment: Also is there really no easy way to keep the quoting done on certain existing arguments? This is the main thing i struggled with, since adding a flag at the end using the original snippet in my post is easier (as you mentioned too)

Comment: @NordineLotfi, err, I'm not sure what you mean. The way to keep the arguments intact is to use `"$@"` or, for one or more args, but not the whole list, something like `"$3"` or `"${@:2:3}"`. There are no quotes at this point. And yes, I switched to `if`, since I'm not sure what to do from the third try on. But you could do `if ! "$@"; then while ! "$@" --otherarg; do sleep 1; done; fi` to keep looping on the modified command line.

Comment: I meant to keep the specific `quote` that could be placed (as the example used in my post) on the command passed to the retry function. I know how to escape them (as mentioned and linked to a solution that do this in my post) but don't know how to keep them intact...my guess is that placing single quote around double quote would work but not sure how to do this

Comment: @NordineLotfi, if you call a script on the shell command line as `retry.sh ls pattern "file name"`, then you get `ls`, `pattern`, and `file name` in `$1`, `$2` and `$3`. `"$@"` expands to those three words, the same as if the script contained `"$1" "$2" "$3"` (except that `"$@"` doesn't require knowing the number of arguments). If you call the script as `retry.sh ls pattern file\ name`, you get the same. The quotes and escapes are removed when the command line is processed, so when you're in the script, you don't have any quotes to deal with, but individual positional parameters.

Comment: and of course if that third argument doesn't contain any white space, then you can enter it on the command line as `file` or `"file"` and it makes no difference. In any case, if you want to add a new command-line argument, there's no need to touch the existing words you have in the positional parameters, in `$@`, just add a new one.