# How to match a literal string containing an unclosed quote with ripgrep?

Tags: quoting, pattern-matching, ripgrep

I have a file that contains the some python code. There is a line that contains the following(including the quotes)

`'hello "value"'`

I want to search `'hello "value"` in the file. Notice the unclosed quote. I'm using ripgrep with the folowing command:

`rg -F 'hello "value"`

The above command is not working for the input `'hello "value"` in bash/ zsh. All i want is the literal match. I have used the flag `F` but because of unclosed quotes in the input string it is not working at all. I also tried enclosing the input inside single/ double quotes as so:

`rg -F "'hello "value""` or `rg -F ''hello "value"'`

The above is not working as well.

I thought the  `F` flag would tell ripgrep to consider the input literally as it is? How do I fix this?

Comment: One `brute-force way` is to backslash the shell metacharacters on the command line,as in: `\'hello\ \"value\"` Admittedly, this isn't the best of ways, but gets the job done.

Answer (score 13):

The text `'hello "value"` *as seen by the shell* starts with a single quote and never ends it. You'll get a continuation prompt (`$PS2`, often `>`) asking for the rest of the string.

To search for something like this you would need to escape the quotes (both sorts) from the shell, which you can do like this

```
"'hello \"value\""
```

Or if you don't want to escape all the literal double quotes, quote the initial single quote and leave the rest of the string single-quoted

```
"'"'hello "value"'
^1 ^3            ^4      
  ^2
```

- 1-2 double-quoted string containing the initial leading single-quote mark
- 3-4 single-quoted string containing literal double-quote marks

If you have particularly complicated strings there would be nothing wrong with you reading the string from the script, where the shell can be instructed not to try to parse it, rather than on the command line, where it *will* attempt to parse it

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $# -eq 0 ]] && IFS= read -rp "Enter search string: " item
rg -F "${1:-$item}"
```

Make the script executable and put it somewhere in your `$PATH`. If you provide something on the command line it will use it. If you don't, it will prompt for the string and you can enter one with as much complexity as you like.

---

As a footnote, possibly part of the confusion is the expectation from the Windows/DOS world that the program itself parses the command line. This is not the case in the UNIX/Linux world, where the shell parses the command line and passes the resulting arguments to the command. There is no way to tell to the shell not to parse the command line - that's what it does - so you need to work with that or else bypass the shell. Related reading is [How to escape quotes in shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30903/100397) and [What is the difference between the “…”, '…', $'…', and $“…” quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/100397)
, which explain in much more detail about quoting quotes, etc.

Comment: I understood your point and it is working perfectly. What if it is a complex string, there is no simple way to tell ripgrep, hey i want to search `"[]'some'string'90'';"$%6^~'`, please search it as it is.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/how-to-escape-quotes-in-shell and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503013/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-quotes-in-th

Comment: @HarisMuzaffar answer updated to offer an alternative to command-line processing

Answer (score 5):

If the string requires quoting from hell, you could take the help of `heredoc` to throw you a lifeline:

```
rg -Ff - <<\! your_file_python
'hello "value"
!
```

Alternatively, you can throw all these nasty regexes inside a file, away from the prying eyes of the shell, and have them used by ripgrep via the -f file option.

Comment: This useless-use-of-`cat`  seems even *more* useless than most: you already explicitly mention `-` in the `rg` command line, and using cat just makes you mention it again.  `<<!` can appear anywhere within the `rg` command, for example `rg -Ff - <<! your_file_python`

Comment: Fixed now. Thanks for the improvement.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit on [roaima's
answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/650611/72304) - if you use
Bash you could use printf's `%q` modifier which *causes printf to output
the corresponding argument in a format that can be reused as shell
input*. A useful one-liner would be:

```
read -r &&  printf "%q\n" "$REPLY"
```

Type a string literally, press <kbd>Return</kbd>, and `printf` will display a
correctly quoted string you can pass to shell commands.

Example:

```
$ read -r &&  printf "%q\n" "$REPLY"
'hello "value"'
\'hello\ \"value\"\'
$ echo \'hello\ \"value\"\'
'hello "value"'
```

Comment: A bare `read` will process your input string somewhat. For example try `bb\n` (the literal four characters)

Comment: I added `-r`, typical shellcheck warning, sorry