# Escape character(single-quotes) not working in Linux alias

Tags: linux, alias, escape-characters

I was trying to play around with escape characters in aliases.

Here's a simple example :
I want to create an alias for

`echo 'Hello'`

So I wrote the alias like below :

`alias sample 'echo \'Hello\' '`

But I see this when I try to source the alias :

> Unmatched '.

Any idea why this could be happening?

PS : I know I can use `alias "echo 'Hello'"` , but I want to test out the escaping in aliases.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape quotes in shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/how-to-escape-quotes-in-shell)

Comment: @mashuptwice The alias syntax is incorrect for `bash` or any other `sh`-like shell.  It is however the correct syntax for `csh` or `tcsh`.  The last `alias` command is nonsensical though.  The error message is _identical_ to what `csh` (but not `tcsh`) would produce.  The `bash` shell would not produce that error.

Comment: What shell are you currently using? Is it the `csh` shell?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment above, your statement is missing the equals sign.  However, consider using a Bash [function](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) instead, which are more flexible:

sample() {
    echo \'Hello\'
}