Script with command as different user
I am trying to run the following script in Ubuntu -

declare -a loggedOnUsers

readarray -t loggedOnUsers < <( w -h | awk '{print $1}' )

for loggedOnUser in "${loggedOnUsers[@]}"

do

/bin/su -c "gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "['google-chrome.desktop','org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop']"" - $loggedOnUser

done


It works for another command in another script without issues. I think it's to do with the quotes and double quotes causing issues but I cannot figure out how to make this work. Is anyone able to advise where I have gone wrong?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30903/639822

The syntax highlighting in the code block in your question might give a hint about the problem. If you take a closer look, the left bracket [ is black, but the surrounding text is green (the color reserved for quoted text), which means the bracket is not considered as being inside of the quoted argument. In order to include the literal double quote character inside of the double quoted argument, it needs to be escaped with a backslash: \". Also, you should quote the loggedOnUser parameter substitution (command split into multiple lines for readability; when splitting a quoted argument like this, take care not to indent any lines which are a part of it):
/bin/su -c "gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps \
\"['google-chrome.desktop','org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop']\"" \
    - "$loggedOnUser"

In general, it is advisable to run shellcheck(1) on your scripts to check them for common programming mistakes, or paste them on shellcheck.net.
Related reading: Double Quotes (Bash Reference Manual).
Additionally, the script can be simplified by using users(1) instead of w(1) + awk(1) and made more portable by not requiring arrays:
#!/bin/sh
for user in $(users); do
    /bin/su -c "gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps \
\"['google-chrome.desktop','org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop']\"" \
        - "$user"
done

